# Boto3 uploading to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to add an String, created by an lambda, to a existing textfile on my s3 bucket.

When I use:

```
s3.Object('My_bucket', 'textfile.txt').put(Body=missingtagginginfo)
```

missingtagginginfo = My created variable
textfile.txt = textfile that exists on the s3 bucket

I get the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",
```

"errorType": "ClientError",

I alreday gave the lambda the s3fullAccess.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

greets

Comment: Check if bucket policy (not IAM policy) has any `Deny` rules

Comment: the bucket hasnt got any deny rules and all the public access rules are deactivated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy must contain `s3:PutObject` in order to upload objects.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/",
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/*"
    ]
}
```

Please don't add wildcard permissions (`s3:*`) or wildcard resources (`"Resource": [ "*" ]`) as these give huge potential for bugs and vulnerabilities. The [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

The IAM Policy looks like this:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/",
            "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Comment: This policy doesn't allow `s3:PutObject` and also it's not clear who is the principal (who performs the actions). In general if you are not sure about permissions, use https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/ to test it

Comment: So to fix it just add the 's3:PutObject' and the principal to the IAM oder bucket policy?

Comment: In general yes, but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing full policy

Comment: Yes. You should also put the policy into the question instead of an answer.

Comment: I've added an answer that includes the required permission. Would you mind taking this down as it is not a solution, but just added information for your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Write in Your Bucket's Policy

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow-OAI-Access-To-Bucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Your-Bucket-Name/*"
    }
]
}
```